# How would I prove $-a=(-1)a$ for any integer $a$ using Peano axioms?

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation, solution-verification, axioms

How can I prove that for any integer $a$ it holds that $-a=(-1)a$ using Peano axioms? I think that it can be partially proven with the distributive property, multiplicative identity, and additive inverses property, but I think it's lacking and I'm not sure if it is correct. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Well, $-a$ is the **unique** integer so that $a+(-a) = 0$. Check that the same holds for $(-1)a$ and you are done.

Comment: [Peano axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms) are about *natural* number: there are no negative ones.

Comment: It's even literally one of the axioms: there is no number whose successor is 0.

Comment: You should check out Landau's *Foundations of Analysis*, where he derives all the usual properties of the complex numbers, starting from Peano. It's remarkably readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Peano axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms) are about natural number: $-a$ is not defined.

You have to use the [Axioms for rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer#Algebraic_properties) and the *existence of inverse elements*:

> $a + (-a)=0$.

*Proof sketch*:

> $1+(-1)=0$, thus: $(1+(-1)) \times a = 0 \times a =0$. By distributivity : $(1 \times a)+ ((-1) \times a)=0$.

Finally, "comparing" $a+((−1)×a)=0$ with $a+(−a)=0$, gives us the desired result.